# Calculus treatment of independent variables in differential equations

Tags: calculus

In Schaum Outline Series (Lagrangian dynamics) page 41 it states, with $\normalsize x = x(q_1,q_2)$ with $\normalsize q_1, q_2$ being generalised coordinates and $\dot{x}$,  $\dot{q_1}$, $\dot{q_2}$ being the first derivative of $\normalsize x$, $q_1$, $q_2$ relative to t:

$$\dot{x} = \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1} \dot{q_1} + \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_2} \dot{q_2}\tag{1}$$

The book then says differentiating this partially with respect to $\normalsize\dot{q_1}$ (1) becomes :

$$\frac {\partial \dot{x}}{\partial \dot{q_1}} = \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1}\tag{2}    $$

However I can't see how (2) is derived from the full partial derivative chain rule applied to (1) with respect to $\normalsize\dot{q_1}$:

$$\frac {\partial \dot{x}}{\partial \dot{q_1}} = \dot{q_1} \frac {\partial }{\partial \dot{q_1}}( \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1})+ \frac {\partial \dot{q_1}}{\partial \dot{q_1}} \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1}  + \dot{q_2} \frac {\partial }{\partial \dot{q_1}}( \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_2})+ \frac {\partial \dot{q_2}}{\partial \dot{q_1}} \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_2}  \tag{3}    $$

giving more terms on the right hand side than in (2)

$$\frac {\partial \dot{x}}{\partial \dot{q_1}} = \dot{q_1} \frac {\partial }{\partial \dot{q_1}}( \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1})+  \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1}  + \dot{q_2} \frac {\partial }{\partial \dot{q_1}}( \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_2})+ \frac {\partial \dot{q_2}}{\partial \dot{q_1}} \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_2}  \tag{4}    $$

Comment: The second fraction does not depent on $\dot q_1$ thats why it's zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x$ is a function of $q_1,\,q_2$, neither $x$ nor $\partial x/\partial q_i$ depend on $\dot{q}_j$.

Comment: I was wondering why would x(q1,q2) exclude a dependence upon the derivatives of q1 & q2? Is there some convention that is being applied here as I thought x(q1,q2) means any function of q1 & q2, which would include derivatives etc.?

Comment: @LittleCheese With partial derivatives, the "dependence" is only on what's shown explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dot{x} = \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1} \dot{q_1} + \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_2} \dot{q_2}$$
$\frac {\partial x}{\partial q_2} \dot{q_2} $ doesn't depend on $\dot q_1$ so it's partial derivative is zero. Then:
$$\frac {\partial \dot{x}}{\partial \dot{q_1}} = \frac {\partial }{\partial \dot{q_1}} \left ( \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1} \dot{q_1} \right )=\frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1} \left ( \frac {\partial }{\partial \dot{q_1}} \dot{q_1} \right )$$
Therefore :
$$\frac {\partial \dot{x}}{\partial \dot{q_1}} = \frac {\partial x}{\partial q_1}$$